# cast FrameLayout to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am recently trying to understand a [sample](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/blob/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentLayout.java) about fragment. For this [line](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/blob/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentLayout.java#L144-L145), concretely:

```
DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
```

where

```
public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment{
...
}
```

and the [layout.xml](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/blob/master/samples/ApiDemos/res/layout-land/fragment_layout.xml) is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is why method `findFragmentById` that receives an argument of `FrameLayout` will return an object of `Fragment` in a way like type casting? However, `FrameLayout` extends `ViewGroup` and `Fragment` extends `java.lang.Object`, they do not share a common super class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another way to find fragment like this..

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DetailsFragment .getClass().getName());

if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof DetailsFragment ) {
    //fragment to call DetailsFragment's method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Other way is to store Fragment classes casting like this

`Class<? extends Fragment> fragmentClass = AboutFragment.class;`